# Selenium package [org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver etc] is not accessible even after adding it

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, jar

I have tried to Selenium jar files using module path and class path but still the selenium function is not recognising
PFA image

[image: pfa image]

I have followed the below step

Adding Jar File in Module path

1. Right click on project
2. Select properties
3. Under Java Build path Select modulepath and select add external jar
4. Add all Jar file of Selenium
5. Select Apply and close

Adding Jar File in Module path

1. Right click on project
2. Select properties
3. Under Java Build path Select classpath and select add external jar
4. Add all Jar file of Selenium
5. Select Apply and close

Adding Jar File in Class path (User Library)

1. Right click on project
2. Select properties
3. Under Java Build path Select classpath and select add Library
4. Select user libraries, select new and add names
5. From Add external Library add the library
6. Select Apply and close and the finish it

Comment: Delete your `module-info.java` file (if needed you can recreate it later via right-click on project and _Configure_) or [in `module-info.java` add the required `requires ...;` statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System#Properties_of_modules).